# Use JGit to fetch git repo with InMemoryRepository and SSH

Tags: jgit, apache-sshd

I'm using JGit in a webservice, that needs to pull/fetch from multiple repositories. Therefore, I'm using the `InMemoryRepository` of JGit. Additionally, I want to access the repo using SSH (private/public RSA key pair).

As described in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549456 it seems that this is not possible. I found [another post](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547619), where Thomas Wolf describes how this could be achieved.

Somehow this doesn't work for me. So far this is my code.

```java
private void fetchGitRepository(String repositoryUri, java.security.KeyPair keyPair) {
    DfsRepositoryDescription repoDesc = new DfsRepositoryDescription();
    Repository repository = new InMemoryRepository(repoDesc);
    repository.getObjectDatabase();

    try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
        FetchCommand fetchCommand = git.fetch()
                .setRemote(repositoryUri)
                .setRefSpecs(new RefSpec("+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"));

        if (keyPair != null) {
            SshTransportConfigCallback transportConfigCallback = new SshTransportConfigCallback(keyPair);
            fetchCommand.setTransportConfigCallback(transportConfigCallback);
        }

        fetchCommand.call();
    }
}

class SshTransportConfigCallback implements TransportConfigCallback {
    private KeyPair keyPair;

    public SshTransportConfigCallback(KeyPair keyPair) {
        this.keyPair = keyPair;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Transport transport) {
        if (transport instanceof SshTransport) {
            SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
            sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(new MySessionFactory(keyPair));
        }
    }

    private static class MySessionFactory extends SshdSessionFactory {
        private final KeyPair keyPair;

        public MySessionFactory(KeyPair keyPair) {
            this.keyPair = keyPair;
        }

        @Override
        public File getHomeDirectory() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public File getSshDirectory() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected File getSshConfig(File sshDir) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected ServerKeyDatabase getServerKeyDatabase(File homeDir, File sshDir) {
            return new ServerKeyDatabase() {
                @Override
                public List<PublicKey> lookup(String connectAddress, InetSocketAddress remoteAddress, Configuration config) {
                    return emptyList();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean accept(String connectAddress, InetSocketAddress remoteAddress, PublicKey serverKey, Configuration config, CredentialsProvider provider) {
                    return true; // TODO: Fix this later
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Path> getDefaultKnownHostsFiles(File sshDir) {
            return emptyList();
        }

        @Override
        protected Iterable<KeyPair> getDefaultKeys(File sshDir) {
            return of(keyPair);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Path> getDefaultIdentities(File sshDir) {
            return emptyList();
        }

        @Override
        protected String getDefaultPreferredAuthentications() {
            return "publickey";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
2021-10-23 18:04:49.773 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector    : Connecting to github.com/140.82.121.3:22
2021-10-23 18:04:49.774 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector    : setOption(SO_REUSEADDR)[true] from property=Property[socket-reuseaddr](Boolean]
2021-10-23 18:04:49.801 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : Creating IoSession on /192.168.178.37:52145 from github.com/140.82.121.3:22 via null
2021-10-23 18:04:49.801 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : Client session created: Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]
2021-10-23 18:04:49.801 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : ClientUserAuthService(JGitClientSession[null@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) use configured preferences: publickey
2021-10-23 18:04:49.801 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : ClientUserAuthService(JGitClientSession[null@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) client methods: [publickey]
2021-10-23 18:04:49.802 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.a.s.c.s.h.SessionTimeoutListener       : sessionCreated(JGitClientSession[null@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) tracking
2021-10-23 18:04:49.802 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : initializeProxyConnector(JGitClientSession[null@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) no proxy to initialize
2021-10-23 18:04:49.802 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : sendIdentification(JGitClientSession[null@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]): SSH-2.0-APACHE-SSHD-2.7.0
2021-10-23 18:04:49.802 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : writeBuffer(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) writing 27 bytes
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : HostKeyAlgorithms [ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ssh-ed25519, sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com, sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-dss]
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] s.c.k.e.DefaultClientKexExtensionHandler : handleKexInitProposal(JGitClientSession[null@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]): proposing HostKeyAlgorithms [ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ssh-ed25519, sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com, sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-dss, ext-info-c]
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : sendKexInit(JGitClientSession[null@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Send SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : encode(JGitClientSession[null@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) packet #0 sending command=20[SSH_MSG_KEXINIT] len=1304
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : writeBuffer(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) writing 1320 bytes
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.future.DefaultConnectFuture      : Connected to github.com/140.82.121.3:22 after 601766936 nanos
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : doReadIdentification(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) line: SSH-2.0-babeld-abb5d94f
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : readIdentification(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Server version string: SSH-2.0-babeld-abb5d94f
2021-10-23 18:04:50.375 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : auth(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[ssh-connection] send SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST for 'none'
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : handleKexInit(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : enqueuePendingPacket(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST] Start flagging packets as pending until key exchange is done
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com none
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com none
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: kex algorithms = ecdh-sha2-nistp521
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: server host key algorithms = rsa-sha2-512
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: encryption algorithms (client to server) = aes128-ctr
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: encryption algorithms (server to client) = aes128-ctr
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: mac algorithms (client to server) = hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: mac algorithms (server to client) = hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: compression algorithms (client to server) = none
2021-10-23 18:04:50.376 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setNegotiationResult(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Kex: compression algorithms (server to client) = none
2021-10-23 18:04:50.380 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] org.apache.sshd.client.kex.DHGClient     : init(DHGClient[ecdh-sha2-nistp521])[JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]] Send SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
2021-10-23 18:04:50.380 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : encode(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) packet #1 sending command=30[30] len=138
2021-10-23 18:04:50.380 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-1] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : writeBuffer(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) writing 152 bytes
2021-10-23 18:04:50.495 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] org.apache.sshd.client.kex.DHGClient     : next(DHGClient[ecdh-sha2-nistp521])[JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]] process command=SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
2021-10-23 18:04:50.503 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : setServerKey(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) keyType=ssh-rsa, digest=SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
2021-10-23 18:04:50.503 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : handleKexMessage(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[ecdh-sha2-nistp521] KEX processing complete after cmd=31
2021-10-23 18:04:50.995 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : checkKeys(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) key=ssh-rsa-SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8, verified=true
2021-10-23 18:04:50.996 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : sendNewKeys(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Send SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
2021-10-23 18:04:50.996 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : encode(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) packet #2 sending command=21[SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS] len=1
2021-10-23 18:04:50.996 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : writeBuffer(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) writing 16 bytes
2021-10-23 18:04:50.996 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : handleNewKeys(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS command=SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
2021-10-23 18:04:50.996 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : receiveNewKeys(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) session ID=37:31:1f:99:1c:de:35:10:3c:e7:31:be:39:5b:ca:b0:5b:c0:e6:89:92:9c:6e:c2:cf:77:e9:a6:12:a7:3b:aa:ca:12:61:1e:43:b1:a4:d3:7e:30:a9:98:43:c4:76:b3:fd:f9:2c:a7:1d:e9:de:1c:c5:b4:90:ca:0e:c5:78:94
2021-10-23 18:04:50.997 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : receiveNewKeys(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) inCipher=BaseCipher[AES, ivSize=16, kdfSize=16,AES/CTR/NoPadding, blkSize=16], outCipher=BaseCipher[AES, ivSize=16, kdfSize=16,AES/CTR/NoPadding, blkSize=16], recommended blocks limit=4294967296, actual=4294967296
2021-10-23 18:04:50.997 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : sendInitialServiceRequest(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Send SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST for ssh-userauth
2021-10-23 18:04:50.997 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : encode(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) packet #3 sending command=5[SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST] len=17
2021-10-23 18:04:50.997 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : writeBuffer(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) writing 84 bytes
2021-10-23 18:04:50.997 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : encode(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) packet #4 sending command=50[SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST] len=34
2021-10-23 18:04:50.997 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : writeBuffer(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) writing 100 bytes
2021-10-23 18:04:50.997 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : handleNewKeys(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) sent 1 pending packets
2021-10-23 18:04:51.099 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-3] s.c.k.e.DefaultClientKexExtensionHandler : handleServerSignatureAlgorithms(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]): [ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com, sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com, sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com, ssh-ed25519, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-dss]
2021-10-23 18:04:51.099 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-3] s.c.k.e.DefaultClientKexExtensionHandler : handleServerSignatureAlgorithms(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]): PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms before: [ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ssh-ed25519, sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com, sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-dss]
2021-10-23 18:04:51.099 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-3] s.c.k.e.DefaultClientKexExtensionHandler : handleServerSignatureAlgorithms(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]): PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms after: [ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ssh-ed25519, sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com, sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-dss]
2021-10-23 18:04:51.118 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-4] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : handleServiceAccept(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT service=ssh-userauth
2021-10-23 18:04:51.157 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : processUserAuth(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Received SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE - partial=false, methods=publickey
2021-10-23 18:04:51.157 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : tryNext(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) starting authentication mechanisms: client=[publickey], server=[publickey]
2021-10-23 18:04:51.157 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : tryNext(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) attempting method=publickey
2021-10-23 18:04:51.158 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-5] o.e.j.i.t.s.JGitPublicKeyAuthentication  : sendAuthDataRequest(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[ssh-connection] send SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST request publickey type=rsa-sha2-512 - fingerprint=SHA256:wtyx9w1r6/ELRZtxJAwXjHmnIyeeQenDhh94q4HJgxE
2021-10-23 18:04:51.158 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-5] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : encode(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) packet #5 sending command=50[SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST] len=211
2021-10-23 18:04:51.158 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : writeBuffer(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) writing 276 bytes
2021-10-23 18:04:51.158 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : tryNext(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) successfully processed initial buffer by method=publickey
2021-10-23 18:04:51.282 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-6] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : processUserAuth(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Received SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE - partial=false, methods=publickey
2021-10-23 18:04:51.282 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-6] o.e.j.i.t.s.JGitPublicKeyAuthentication  : sendAuthDataRequest(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[ssh-connection] server rejected publickey authentication with known signature algorithm rsa-sha2-512
2021-10-23 18:04:51.282 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-6] o.e.j.i.t.s.JGitPublicKeyAuthentication  : resolveAttemptedPublicKeyIdentity(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[ssh-connection] no more keys to send
2021-10-23 18:04:51.282 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-6] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : tryNext(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) no initial request sent by method=publickey
2021-10-23 18:04:51.282 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-6] o.e.j.i.t.s.JGitPublicKeyAuthentication  : destroy(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[ssh-connection]
2021-10-23 18:04:51.282 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-6] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : tryNext(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) exhausted all methods - client=[publickey], server=[publickey]
2021-10-23 18:04:52.465 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : close(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Closing immediately
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : signalAuthFailure(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) type=SshException, signalled=false, first=false: Session is being closed
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.s.h.SessionTimeoutListener       : sessionClosed(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) un-tracked
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : close(org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService@cd3cad2) Closing immediately
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientUserAuthService    : close(org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService@cd3cad2)[Immediately] closed
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientConnectionService  : close(ClientConnectionService[JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]]) Closing immediately
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientConnectionService  : stopHeartBeat(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) no heartbeat to stop
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.session.ClientConnectionService  : close(ClientConnectionService[JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22]])[Immediately] closed
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : close(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) Closing immediately
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : doCloseImmediately(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) closing socket=sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl[connected local=/192.168.178.37:52145 remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : doCloseImmediately(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) socket=sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl[closed] closed
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector    : unmapSession(id=104): Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : close(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[Immediately] state already Immediate
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : close(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[Immediately] closed
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.u.closeable.SequentialCloseable  : doClose(org.apache.sshd.common.util.closeable.SequentialCloseable$1@5b272ea5) signal close complete immediately=true
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.e.j.i.t.sshd.JGitClientSession         : close(JGitClientSession[git@github.com/140.82.121.3:22])[Immediately] closed
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- []-nio2-thread-7] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session      : handleReadCycleFailure(Nio2Session[local=/192.168.178.37:52145, remote=github.com/140.82.121.3:22]) AsynchronousCloseException after 1183659791 nanos at read cycle=7: null
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.e.j.i.transport.sshd.JGitSshClient     : close(JGitSshClient[97d9893]) Closing immediately
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector    : close(org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector@7cd2a6a6) Closing immediately
2021-10-23 18:04:52.466 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector    : close(org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector@7cd2a6a6)[Immediately] closed
2021-10-23 18:04:52.467 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.s.c.u.closeable.SequentialCloseable  : doClose(org.apache.sshd.common.util.closeable.SequentialCloseable$1@7cced81d) signal close complete immediately=true
2021-10-23 18:04:52.467 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.e.j.i.transport.sshd.JGitSshClient     : close(JGitSshClient[97d9893])[Immediately] closed
2021-10-23 18:04:52.468 DEBUG 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: com.mlaide.webserver.service.git.GitDiffException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:MLAide/python-client.git: Cannot log in at github.com:22
2021-10-23 18:04:52.469 ERROR 25750 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.mlaide.webserver.service.git.GitDiffException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:MLAide/python-client.git: Cannot log in at github.com:22] with root cause

org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: No more authentication methods available
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService.tryNext(ClientUserAuthService.java:353) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService.processUserAuth(ClientUserAuthService.java:288) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService.process(ClientUserAuthService.java:225) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.AbstractSession.doHandleMessage(AbstractSession.java:503) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.AbstractSession.handleMessage(AbstractSession.java:429) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.AbstractSession.decode(AbstractSession.java:1466) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.AbstractSession.messageReceived(AbstractSession.java:389) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.transport.sshd.JGitClientSession.messageReceived(JGitClientSession.java:198) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache-5.13.0.202109080827-r.jar:5.13.0.202109080827-r]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.AbstractSessionIoHandler.messageReceived(AbstractSessionIoHandler.java:64) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.handleReadCycleCompletion(Nio2Session.java:359) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:336) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:333) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.lambda$completed$0(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:38) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.completed(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:37) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:221) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:113) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I used the following library versions:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0.202109080827-r</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0.202109080827-r</version>
        </dependency>
```